Leveraging Mathematica's Capabilities for Building an Advanced Mathematical Database and Theorem Proving Syst
This is going to be an important and interesting question about the theorem proving capabilities of Mathematica and  may  be it has been asked before here but with the advent of LLM's the question becomes all the more significant Mathematica is renowned for its powerful capabilities in mathematical computations. With its comprehensive tools and Wolfram Language's flexibility, it seems uniquely positioned to contribute significantly to areas beyond traditional computation. One such potential avenue is the creation of a comprehensive mathematical database, encompassing theorems, definitions, and proofs, which could serve as the foundation for an advanced automatic theorem proving system.
Considering the intersections between mathematics, computer science, and AI, such a system could not only enhance mathematical research but also contribute to improving the reasoning capabilities of large language models (LLMs). Ilya Sutskever, in his 2020 paper, pointed to the significant potential of leveraging theorem proving in advancing AI's reasoning abilities. This approach suggests a profound synergy between Mathematica's computational strengths and the frontiers of AI research.
Given the apparent potential and benefits, it raises the question: Why hasn't there been a more pronounced effort towards developing such a mathematical database and theorem proving system within the Mathematica ecosystem? Is it a matter of technical challenges, prioritization, or perhaps something else?
Additionally, how could such a system, if developed, be leveraged to enhance the reasoning capabilities of LLMs and contribute to broader AI research? Are there examples or initiatives within the Mathematica community that have explored similar directions?
I'm curious to hear the community's thoughts on the feasibility, potential challenges, and implications of such an initiative. Your insights could shed light on the untapped potential of Mathematica and its role in advancing both mathematical research and AI.
Thank you for your time and thoughts.

fyi, see this post at Fricas forum by Tim Daly. He is doing lots of research in this area and mentions some software he is using (LEAN from CMU)  for automated proof and using LLM's.  LEAN is a CMU/MS project[0][1]
They have a proof assistant and a rapidly growing database of theorems
and proofs. link to paper

Thank you for the wonderful links @Nasser

I don't understand why they close a question that might interest so mnay over here about mathematica
